# Initialize PhoneGap Plugin BarcodeScanner in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, barcode

I wanted to use barcode scanning in my App and tried to use the BarcodeScanner [BarcodeScanner](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/BarcodeScanner) plugin for PhoneGap (I build a project for iOS).

Since the explanations given are aiming on a previous version of PhoneGap, I have trouble to initialize the plugin. I think it has something to do with the plugin integration in the *config.xml* file.

Currently I have added the following line:

Beside that I did everthing mentioned in the plugin description.

When trying to scan a specific barcode with:

```
window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan()
```

I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'window.plugins.barcodeScanner')
```

Thanks for helping me out,

Christoph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had trouble until I replaced the line in my config with this

`<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.barcodeScanner" value="CDVBarcodeScanner" />`

and in the Classes/Commands/CDVPlugin.h file, changed these lines:

```
NSString* const CDVPageDidLoadNotification;
NSString* const CDVPluginHandleOpenURLNotification;
NSString* const CDVPluginResetNotification;
NSString* const CDVLocalNotification;
```

to this:

```
extern NSString* const CDVPageDidLoadNotification;
extern NSString* const CDVPluginHandleOpenURLNotification;
extern NSString* const CDVPluginResetNotification;
extern NSString* const CDVLocalNotification;
```

Comment: Joe - were there any other departures from these instructions? https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/BarcodeScanner

Comment: No, think that was it I think - what's the problem? If you want a custom XIB overlay, you need to use CDVbcsViewController instead of PGbcsViewController as referenced in step 7.